# Deprecation warning error rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have rails 4.2.0. Whenever I try to run *rake assets precompile* I got this:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly. (called from  at /Users/santiagocarreno/Desktop/vownu/config/application.rb:22)

I've already change the config.serve_static_assets line to config.serve_static_files but it doesnt work, how can I fix this, this error is not allowing me to update my app on heroku

Comment: Restart Rails application and [spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) preloader if you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run this in the console:

```
bundle update rails_serve_static_assets
```

and the warning disappears, it worked for me so I hope help you.